# mutlple jquery toggles how to go back to default?

Tags: jquery, toggle

I have 2 click elements (divs - #click1, #click2), and 3 content elements (tables - #default, #table1, #table2).

when you click #click1, it hides #default (and #table2 if needed), and shows #table1, and #click2 hides other tables, and shows #table2.

if all #table1 and #table2 are hidden, I would like to have #default show, and it is not acting like that.

The best I could come up with does not work :

```
$( "#default:hidden" ) && $( "#table1:hidden" ) && $( "#table2:hidden" ) {
    $( "#default" ).show();
});
```

html:

```
<div class="container">
<div id="click1" class="button">
    Click 1
</div>
<div id="click2" class="button">
    Click 2
</div>
<div class="tables">
    <table id="default">
        <tr><td>Default Info</td><td>Default Info</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Default Info</td><td>Default Info</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table id="table1">
        <tr><td>Info1</td><td>info1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Info1</td><td>info1</td></tr>
    </table>
    <table id="table2">
        <tr><td>Info2</td><td>info2</td></tr>
        <tr><td>Info2</td><td>info2</td></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
width:80%;
text-align:center;
margin:0 auto;
}
.button {
width:100px;
display:inline-block;
border:2px solid blue;
}
.tables {
width:50%;
margin:0 auto;
}
table {
border:1px solid red;
text-align:center;
width:100%;
}
#table1, #table2 {
display:none;
}
```

JS:

```
$( "#click1" ).click(function() {
$( "table2" ).hide("slow", function(){});
$( "#default" ).hide("slow", function(){});
$( "#table1" ).toggle("slow", function(){});
});
$( "#click2" ).click(function() {
$( "#table1" ).hide("slow", function(){});
$( "#default" ).hide("slow", function(){});
$( "#table2" ).toggle("slow", function(){});
});
```

Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SBNxY/103/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SBNxY/105/

Comment: That toggles between the 2 and looks clean, but I am looking for something that goes back to the default view

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/SBNxY/106/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I would set up some kind of active, inactive flag variables and check those on the button clicks to determine the action to take. (i only showed one function below for brevity, the same format applies to both and the JSfiddle has both functions correctly implemented)

See this example for the flag variable method: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/SBNxY/108/)**

```
var table1 = 0, table2 = 0;
$( "#click1" ).click(function() {
    if(table1 == 0) {
        //show + hide
        $( "#table1" ).show("slow");
        $( "#table2" ).hide("slow");
        $( "#default" ).hide("slow");
        //set flags
        table1 = 1;
        table2 = 0;
    }
    else {
        //show + hide
        $( "#default" ).show("slow");
        $( "#table2" ).hide("slow");
        $( "#table1" ).hide("slow");
        //set flags
        table1 = 0;
        table2 = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways of doing this.

Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/a4u0ujoa/, I think it does what you want.

I've created a function that will check if the current element is visible, and hide/show accordingly or it will show the default if both are hidden:

```
function toggleInfoTable(element)
{
    //see if the element is visible:
    var vis = element.is(":visible")
    //hide all tables first 
    $(".info-table").hide();
    if (vis)
    {
        //it was visible, it's hidden now so show the default:
        $("#default").show("slow");
    }
    else
    {
        //all elements hidden show this element.
        element.show("slow");
    }
}
```

The function can then be called in the on click event like so:

```
$( "#click2" ).click(function() {
    toggleInfoTable($( "#table2" ))
});
```

Comment: It looks great, thank you for the answer, If I could mark them all as correct I would!

Answer (score 0):

One approach is:

```
// binding a click-handler to all <div> elements whose 'id' starts with
// 'click':
$('div[id^=click]').on('click', function () {
    // getting the numbers from the end of the 'id' string:
    var num = (/\d+$/).exec(this.id);

    // if there is a num, and it's a base-10 number:    
    if (num && parseInt(num, 10)) {
        // the <table> we're toggling is:
        var table = $('#table' + num);
        // we toggle that <table>,
        // then find its sibling elements, and hide them:
        table.toggle('slow').siblings().hide('slow');

        // then we select the '#default' <table> and, if the <table> we
        // toggled is ':hidden' we show the '#default', otherwise we hide it:
        $('#default').toggle('slow', table.is(':hidden'))
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/jonwf2wk/).

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt).
  - [`RegExp.prototype.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).
- jQuery:

  - [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
  - [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).
  - [`siblings()`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/).
  - [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Comment: It looks great, thank you for the answer, If I could mark them all as correct I would!